# Are NCWidgetProviding widgets supported on iOS 14

Tags: swift, xcode, ios14, widgetkit

`NCWidgetProviding` based widgets have been deprecated in favor of Apple's newer `WidgetKit` framework but usually when an API is deprecated there is still some transition period. However my `NCWidgetProviding` based widget won't show in the widgets list for `iOS 14.3`(tested both on device and simulator). Can anyone provide me with more information on that? Is there a way to make `NCWidgetProviding` widgets work on iOS 14?

Comment: The old “Today widgets” are supported in iOS 14. I don’t think you have to do anything special, they should just show up, though they are a little hidden: Go to the widget page (the leftmost home screen), scroll to the bottom and tap Edit, then scroll _back_ to the bottom and tap Customize. That brings up the old interface for adding Today widgets and your app should appear there.

Comment: @Adam that is correct. It took me a lot of time to figure out that the home screen add widget feature is different than the ones on the leftmost screen. Not a great user experience from Apple. Thanks for the tip.